# Why is this batch file not executing automatically?

Tags: batch-file, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

Basically I have a batch file which calls a SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure that interogates that DB for fragmentated tables over 5% fragmented and outputs the report to a text file.

The batch file is set as a Task Scheduler job to run overnight.

In Task Scheduler If I right click the task and select run immediately it executes fine, the script is in turn run on SQL Server and the output is redirected to a text file, everything is working as desired at this point, the problem is when I automate it to trigger overnight.

```
set local
REM Preparing Timestamp Information
set year=%date:~6,4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set hour=%time:~0,2%
REM Replace leading space with zero
if “%hour:~0,1%” ==” ” set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set minute=%time:~3,2%
set seconds=%time:~6,2%
set FILENAMEANDPATH= c:\DBMaintenanceLogs\SP_InspectorLog_%day%-%month%-%year%_%hour%-%minute%-%seconds%.log

sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q "EXEC sp_DBIndexFragmentationInspector @IndexFragmentationPercentage=5" -d MyDBName -o %FILENAMEANDPATH%
```

The problem is that when left alone the Task Scheduler job will not run and the task says completed successfully with return code 255?

The Task is set to run using the system administrator account.

P.S. The Stored Procedure is:

```
USE [MyDBName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DBIndexFragmentationInspector]
@IndexFragmentationPercentage INT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(A.[object_id]) as 'TableName',
    B.[name] as 'IndexName',
    A.[index_type_desc],
    A.[avg_fragmentation_in_percent]
FROM
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),NULL,NULL,NULL,'LIMITED') A
INNER JOIN
    sys.indexes B ON A.[object_id] = B.[object_id] and A.index_id = B.index_id 
where [avg_fragmentation_in_percent] > @IndexFragmentationPercentage
order by TableName
END
```

Comment: Are the typographic double quotes in your code `“%hour:~0,1%” ==” ”` , that is, `“”` instead of `""` really present or it is just a copy/paste problem?

Comment: @MCND In the batch file on that line only the double quotes are ” ” and not "", I think that's a hangoever from where I've copied that part of the script from. Do you think that could be an issue? LIke I said it works fine if I execute the task manually.

Comment: your problem is `.\SQLEXPRESS`. Scheduled tasks run in another folder (`%systemroot%\system32`). Use `cd /d "%~dp0` to switch to the folder, where your batchfile is stored.

Comment: @Stephan .\SQLEXPRESS is the SQL Server instance ... the batch file is stored at the root of C:

Comment: If your quotes are the same you have posted, your code will fail from `0:00:00` to `9:59:59` (both `am`) if a space is present as the first character. The `if` will be comparing `openquote space closequote` against `closequote space closequote` (typographic quotes), obviously it will be evaluated as false (`open close != close close` or directly handled as an error as you have a non correctly quoted space) and the space will not be corrected.

Comment: @MCND Ah!.... I will alter the script to `“%hour:~0,1%” ==“ ”` and try again tonight at 1am!

Comment: Better use `if "%hour:~0,1%"==" " set "hour=0%hour:~1,1%"` without typographic quotes.

Comment: or skip the `if` and do just `set "hour=%hour: =0%"` (replace space with zero; if there is no space, it doesn't harm)

Comment: Will try if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set "hour=0%hour:~1,1%" and let you know how it goes tomorrow, thanks to all for your input ;).

Comment: I noticed that in the line `if “%hour:~0,1%” ==” ”` the two quotes have a space in them, that might affect your program

Comment: @MCND That did the trick! it worked at 1am... if you post it as the answer I will accept it... thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked, thank you, but I think that actually the question should be closed as offtopic (there is a `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error` cause).

Comment: I feel that it highlights the importance of using openquote and closequote correctly in batch files... something I was not aware of, and I feel will no doubt prove helpful to others... and also the importance of fully testing your code, i.e. it was not an issue when ran manually because it was never 1am when I did so, and so that incorrect code never fired when ran manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've been confronted with exactly the same error. For me, the solution was to add `exit 0` at the end of the script. I don't understand why but it worked.

Comment: Oo... at the end of the batch file or stored procedure?

Comment: @PaulZahra I've tried both, not sure which one worked. It was about five years ago so I can't remember.

Comment: `exit` is a batch command. The sql script is terminated with `END`. But I can't see, how this could possibly help here.

Comment: There are SQL variations where you can use commands like `exit(n)` or `EXIT n;` or `SETRETURNCODE n`. It depends on which variation you are using (like this: http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/exit-statement.html).